# Extract a variable from a formula

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

my maths a a bit rusty and I need to extract a variable from a formula.
It's needed for a project about air quality in order to convert data from sensors to an index.

The formula is :

$$\left (\frac{D-C}{B-A} \right ) \cdot (E-A)+C$$

And I need to extract $E$.

Would anyone be able to help me to extract it ?

Comment: Extract??? It needs to be an equation if you want to "extract" something out of it (i.e., have it "isolated" on one side of the equation).

Comment: ygosteli Do you have the equation:
$$\left(\frac{D-C}{B-A} \right )\cdot (E-A)+C=0$$
?or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't wrote entirely the equation, my fault...

It was : (D−C/B−A)⋅(E−A)+C=X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring what is on the right hand side, I prefer to suppose that $$\left (\frac{D-C}{B-A} \right ) \cdot (E-A)+C=X$$ and then, doing the same as Evinda did, arrive to 
$$E=\frac{(B C-A D)+(A-B) X}{C-D}$$ If $X=0$, as Evinda assumed, we have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\frac{D-C}{B-A} \right )\cdot (E-A)+C=0 \Rightarrow \left(\frac{D-C}{B-A} \right )\cdot (E-A)=-C \\ \Rightarrow E-A=-C \cdot \frac{B-A}{D-C}, D\neq C \\ \Rightarrow E=A-C \cdot \frac{B-A}{D-C} \\ \Rightarrow E=\frac{A(D-C)-CB+CA}{D-C}=\frac{AD-CA-CB+CA}{D-C}=\frac{AD-CB}{D-C}$$

Comment: $=0$ based on what? (you know what they say about assumption, right?)

Comment: As you said,it should be a equation,and I supposed that he means $=0$..What do they say about assumption? :/

Comment: Sorry, cannot elaborate on that due to website regulations... though, here is a link that might give you a rough idea (I hope I'm not breaking the regulations): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-2NimrRPAQ

Comment: @barakmanos Seems like the kind of movie I'd like. What's it called? Weird that I missed this for so long.

Comment: @GitGud: Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels.

Comment: Thanks, my fault, I was meaning X but forgot to out the entire equation...
As Claude said, your equation is also correct if X = 0
Thanks!

Comment: @barakmanos I already watched it. I don't remember it though. Thanks.